# Hide a product with a certain tag from product-category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tags

I am trying to make products with a certain tag disappear completely from the store, including when customers are browsing categories.

In another question I found this function that help me hide products on the shop page, which is great.

```
    function exclude_specific_tag( $q ) {
    if (is_shop()){
        $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'special' ), // tag name to hide ''
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
        $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'exclude_specific_tag' );
```

Now I need to hide that certain tag from product-categories. The goal is to hide these products with the tag completely from the store, unless I show them in a specific page or post.

Any help and answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add to your condition:

`if (is_shop() || is_product_category()) {`

This will exclude products with the tag from both the shop page and all product categories. You may also want to add `|| is_product_tag()` to make sure they don't show up on tag archives. WooCommerce's [conditional tags reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) can help you find all the conditions you may be interested in using.

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding is_product_category to the function did exactly what I was looking for. I also added that last piece you recommended :)